# SQL Server 2008 result pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table like this:

```
BRAND_IDX | BRAND_NAME | PLATFORM | VIEW_CNT | ORDER_CNT | ORDER_AMOUNT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------


PLATFORM : 100, 200

BRAND_IDX | BRAND_NAME | 100_VIEW_CNT | 100_ORDER_CNT | 100_ORDER_AMOUNT | 200_VIEW_CNT | 200_ORDER_CNT | 200_ORDER_AMOUNT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot is not needed for your result, the output can be achieve by below query

```
SELECT BRAND_IDX,BRAND_NAME,
SUM(CASE WHEN [PLATFORM] =100 THEN [VIEW_CNT] END) AS [100_VIEW_CNT],
SUM(CASE WHEN [PLATFORM] =100 THEN ORDER_CNT END) AS [100_ORDER_CNT],
SUM(CASE WHEN [PLATFORM] =100 THEN ORDER_AMOUNT END) AS [100_ORDER_AMOUNT],
SUM(CASE WHEN [PLATFORM] =200 THEN VIEW_CNT END) AS [200_VIEW_CNT],
SUM(CASE WHEN [PLATFORM] =200 THEN ORDER_CNT END) AS [200_ORDER_CNT],
SUM(CASE WHEN [PLATFORM] =200 THEN ORDER_AMOUNT END) AS [200_ORDER_AMOUNT]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY BRAND_IDX,BRAND_NAME
```

Let me know, if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I will do it this way:

1. Unpivot the table to make it normalized

   ```
   SELECT BRAND_IDX, BRAND_NAME, CAST([PLATFORM] AS VARCHAR) + '_' + COL AS COL, VAL
   INTO #TEST
   FROM Table1
   UNPIVOT
   (
       VAL
       FOR COL IN (VIEW_CNT, ORDER_CNT, ORDER_AMOUNT)
   ) PV
   ```
2. Pivot back based on the column name

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM #TEST2
   PIVOT
   (
       MAX(VAL)
       FOR COL IN ([100_VIEW_CNT],[100_ORDER_CNT],[100_ORDER_AMOUNT],[200_VIEW_CNT],[200_ORDER_CNT],[200_ORDER_AMOUNT])
   ) PV
   ```